# CollectionView generating SIGABRT on pushViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Below function call generating Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x189d35a80).

```
func showChatView(message: ChatMessage) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.chatViewController == nil  {
                let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                self.chatViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VAChatViewController") as? VAChatViewController
                self.chatViewController?.delegate = self;
            }
            self.chatViewController?.messages += [message]

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.chatViewController!, animated: true, completion: {
                let buttonMessage = self.chatViewController?.messages.last
                let hasButtons = buttonMessage?.hasButtons
                if hasButtons! {
                    let vaButtonModel = ChatMessage(buttons: buttonMessage?.buttons)
                    self.chatViewController?.addNewMessage(vaButtonModel)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

One more thing- VAChatViewController implements collectionView to display incoming chat events, which is a response to a string message "xyz". In collectionView delegates I get the array[count] > 0 but it is not calling the collectionView: cellForItemAt after numberOfItems and crashes with SIGABRT followed by above crash. Any idea?

Comment: Post the code of your `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: only the data source is implemented! numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAt: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    } let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]
        switch message.messageType {
        case .chatContent:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ChatCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatCollectionViewCell
            cell.setupWithMessage(message)
            return cell

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. I am calling showChatView: multiple times for the reason I made a single object of ChatViewController, but I forgot to put pushViewController under any check. And, thats the reason of crash. Thanks